# Fill pandas DataFrame with an array based on comparing pandas index and array index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

Here is a dummy code of my application.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import signal

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([3,4,100,6,200,10]),columns=['Data'])
peaks = signal.find_peaks(df['Data'], height=5, threshold=1, distance=1)
x = np.arange(0, len(df))
peaks_index = x[peaks[0]]
peaks_height = peaks[1]['peak_heights']
df['Peaks'] = np.where(df.index.isin(peaks_index), (peaks_height[i] for i in range(len(df))) , 0)
```

I found the peaks in the data via scipy.signal.find_peaks() and want to build a new column with the peaks value. My idea was to compare the dataframe indexes and peaks array indexes, and then fill the columns with peaks value on the indexes at which peaks happen.
In the dataframe, I get objects instead of value and it makes sense with this code, but I couldn't came up with an idea to insert the peaks values. How would you do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try resetting the index so the index is a pandas column and then use the apply function to check if this index column is in the array `peaks_index`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import signal

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([3,4,100,6,200,10]),columns=['Data'])
peaks = signal.find_peaks(df['Data'], height=5, threshold=1, distance=1)
x = np.arange(0, len(df))
peaks_index = x[peaks[0]]
peaks_height = peaks[1]['peak_heights']
df['Peaks'] = df.reset_index().apply(lambda x: x['Data'] if x['index'] in peaks_index else 0, axis=1)
```